# variables in require (dynamic require)

Tags: require

I'm writing an react project, and I want to require imgs src dynamically in jsx render, just like this:

```
return (
    <li className="grid">
        <a href={category.url}>
            <div className="image-wrapper">
                <img className="logo" src={require(category.imgSrc)}/>        //   !!here
            </div>
            <span className="title">{category.name}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    )
```

> //category.imgSrc is like "../../images/01_taxi.png"

however, I got the error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../../01_shunfengche.png'.

so, I try the `require.context` like this

```
var requireContext = require.context("../../../images/",false,/\.png$/);
var imgsrc = requireContext("01_taxi.png");

return (
    <li className="grid">
        <a href={category.url}>
            <div className="image-wrapper">
                <img className="logo" src={imgsrc}/>
            </div>
            <span className="title">{category.name}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    )
```

it still doesn't work, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

finally,i tried this:

```
var requireContext = require.context("../../../images",false,/\.png$/);
    var that = this;
    var lis = this.props.data.map(function(category,index){

        var imgsrc = requireContext("./"+category.img); //here!

        return (
            <li className="grid" data-value={category}>
                <a href={category.url}>
                    <div className="image-wrapper">
                        <img className="logo" src={imgsrc}/>
                    </div>
                    <span className="title">{category.zh_name}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            )
    });
```

write the correct path really does matter.